# Algorithm to find the number of different combinations

Tags: c++, recursion, caching, combinations, dynamic-programming

I am trying to write some code which will find the number of different combinations of numbers from 1 to N, where the maximum sum is equal to S.

I am using a recursive function and Dynamic Programming.

My current program is here:

```
int64 cache[100005];
int64 N;
bool seen[100005];

int64 spend(int64 remainingSum) {
    if (remainingSum == 1) return 1;
    if (seen[remainingSum]) return cache[remainingSum];
    
    int64 differents = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= min(N, remainingSum); i++) {
        differents += spend(remainingSum-i);
    }

    cache[remainingSum] = differents%mod;
    seen[remainingSum] = true;
    return cache[remainingSum];
}
```

Apparently it is not finding all the unique cases.

Comment: *My current program is here:* -- There is no program, only a `spend` function.  A C++ program, a [mcve], would include a `main` and data that drives the program.  Please post this.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the original question from the side where you read it. I cannot understand your explanations. And. Brute Force can never work!